# Good interpolation functions for downscaling magnitude spectrums

Tags: fft, interpolation, spectrogram

I'm trying to downscale a 1D FFT (for displaying an audio spectrogram, like this: [image: courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628773/what-is-on-the-y-axis-of-a-spectrogram-produced-by-pylabs-specgram-function]

My question is: assuming I have a 512 bands spectrum, what would be the recommended interpolation algorithm to rescale the spectrum to 20 bands, for user visualization? Is a simple bilinear filter good enough?

To make my question clearer: I am interested in what the state of the art is regarding this today: what professional tools are used? An answer mentions sinc interpolation which will likely be high quality, but also maybe computationally expensive? Is it the best trade-off for a generic audio visualization tool?

Comment: Why don't you simply average every 16 bins, from the high resolution FFT, to get the each new bin of the 32 bins of the low resolution display...?

Comment: That would probably be computationally simpler, as you don't have to deal with color values at that point, but just magnitudes

Comment: Are your 20 bands you want to keep, are they uniformly sized in terms of linear frequency?  or equal-sized in log frequency?

Comment: @Fat32 just averaging bands 16-by-16 would be a very crude way to go at it. There should at least be some amount of windowing with overlap, and that leads us to this question :-)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I'll have both cases.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, it was not clear in my post but I am indeed referring to downscaling the magnitude spectrum (so an array of 1D values) rather that the rendered image.

Comment: Okay, Jean-Michael, in the log-frequency case. do you want the y-axis to be energy per Hz (linear frequency) or energy per octave (log frequency)?

Comment: hmm to give you some context: I am writing a software framework for various kinds of visualization : I assume that this choice would be one that the user of my system would make depending on what kind of data they want to visualize, not one that I would enforce ?

Answer (score -1):

For visual purposes, I assume that good image scaling methods are a decent starting point. Nothing (?) about a general spectrogram makes it totally unlike a general image in this respect, I think.

Bilinear is not a good algorithm for 20x downscale. For those factors it is going to perform ~ as well as nearest neighbour. A scaling kernel that at least lets all input pixels contribute to the output is a better bet. Lanczos? Gaussian? Triangular?

Answer (score -1):

Downscaling and downsampling are similar concepts.

Sinc interpolation, with the Sinc being a low pass filter kernel appropriate for the new sample rate, is a good method for downsampling interpolation with minimal information loss.  Use a windowed Sinc for a reasonable length approximation filter.  You can calculate the Sinc kernel on the fly, or pre-calculate a polyphase table of FIR filter coefficients.